# Adding cclayer to scene -touches goes down

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Always the same problem .

I have a scene and i am adding it a `CClayer` from another class , which is some background with `ccmenu` on him . 
When touching it,  touches goes under this layer, and i dont want it .

```
otherClass *layer=[otherClass alloc]init]; //otherClass returns a cclayer .
[self addChild: layer];
```

layer is good, and is above my scene , but the touches goes down.
is there a way in cocos2d to enable ONLY touches at the top layer ??
I must change the touches priority now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change touch priority and set to swallowsTouches.
To do this, register your layer on touchDispatcher setting these parameters (you can also see CCLayer `registerWithTouchDispatcher` method as example):

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

Comment: all menus have a priority that puts them ahead of this one, so... they will still be served the touches. You need to set the 'enabled' property of the lower menus to false to prevent them from acting on the touches. Also, you need to add an 'enabled' property to the layers below that process touches, so that they just ignore the touches they receive when enabled==NO;

Comment: so you say that when i add the new layer just disable the lower menus, and than enable them again when i remove that layer ? the problem is that the layer remove it self from his parent and the lower layer dont know about it when the upper one was removed, so he can't enable him self again ..

Comment: Try to notify the upper layer using delegate, like an layerWillBeRemoved: